# How Nested "(" work in python regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, nested

I am trying to extract the values in the ***(...)*** , which may or may not be multiline. And I am using ***"nested ("*** in the regular expression. But it does not work as expected. For simplicity, I changed the regular expression as below;

Code snippet for your reference;

```
RE_MULTI_LINE_PARAMS = ".*"
RE_M_DECLERATION = r"\(%s\)"%RE_MULTI_LINE_PARAMS
...
# read file
fh = open(fname)
fcontent = fh.read()
patternList = re.findall(RE_M_DECLERATION, fcontent, re.VERBOSE)
print patternList
```

In other case, I use;

```
RE_MULTI_LINE_PARAMS = "(.*)"
```

rest of the code as above. But I see difference in the resultant list.

Probably, some one can explain, "why it behaves?" so or "how the nested bracket works in regular expression?"

Comment: .* will match everything till the end of stream since * is greedy

Comment: Why *wouldn't* `(.*)` be different to `\(.*\)`?

Comment: Your question should include the real-life example of what you are trying to match. I suspect you are looking for `[^()]*` pattern (i.e. the whole will look like `\([^()]*\)` and it will match `(` then 0 or more characters other than `(` or `)`, and then `)`).

Comment: To simplify, as per my understanding : `\(.*\)` and `\((.*)\)` should mean the same. But they behave differently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to extract the values in the (...) , which may or may not be multiline.

You need to use flags=re.DOTALL if you want `.*` to be able to include newlines.

> I see difference in the resultant list.

See the [`findall` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group.

When you add a group to your regular expression, it returns only the text *inside* that group. I.e., without including the parentheses. When you don't include a group, it returns the whole text of the match, including the parentheses.

Okay, it sounds like this wasn't clear, so I'll expand a little. When you use `(` and `)` inside a regular expression, you are correct that it does not change which strings the regular expression will match. What the parentheses do is identify a *portion* of the match that will be captured in a numbered "group". So both of your examples will find the same number of matches. *However*, after it has *found* the matches, `findall` has *different* behaviour depending on whether there were any groups defined. If you have defined exactly one group, the contents of that group are returned instead of the whole match.
So for example:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = re.compile(r'\(.*?\)')
>>> b = re.compile(r'\((.*?)\)')
>>> s = 'one (two) three (four) five'
>>> a.findall(s)
['(two)', '(four)']
>>> b.findall(s)
['two', 'four']
```

Both regular expressions match the same strings:

```
>>> [match.group(0) for match in a.finditer(s)]
['(two)', '(four)']
>>> [match.group(0) for match in b.finditer(s)]
['(two)', '(four)']
```

But one of them has a capturing group that selects a portion of the string:

```
>>> [match.groups() for match in b.finditer(s)]
[('two',), ('four',)]
>>> [match.groups() for match in a.finditer(s)]
[(), ()]
```

In addition to these problems, you will find that `.*` matches as much as possible. So for the string `"one (two) three (four)"`, rather than getting matches on `two` and `four`, you're going to get a match on `two) three (four`. You could use a non-greedy match like `.*?` or try to match non-parentheses instead, e.g. something like `[^)]*`.

Comment: The file, that I parse for the pattern, already contains multiple lines. But, my purpose is to only extract the line/multi-line contents, that lie inside `()`. The expression inside may expand, than being `.*`. However, seems from your explanation that, `\(.*\)` and `\((.*)\)` mean different in the regular-expression context

Comment: Does my edit make things clearer? Your expressions *match* the same strings, but *findall* doesn't return *matches*. It returns something different depending on how many groups you define.